# Eclipse Not Indicating Breakpoints With Circle

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, breakpoints

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

Previously (just last Friday), when I was using Eclipse on this machine, it would indicate the breakpoints (whether enables or disabled) using empty or filled circles in both the Java & Debug perspective, e.g. [http://webdev.jhuep.com/~jcs/ejava-javaee/coursedocs/content/html/images/devenv-eclipse-set-breakpoint.png](http://webdev.jhuep.com/%7Ejcs/ejava-javaee/coursedocs/content/html/images/devenv-eclipse-set-breakpoint.png).

However, it is currently not showing said indications any more in both perspectives and I am not sure why!

To clarify, the breakpoints still work. I can see my breakpoints in the `Debug > Breakpoints window` and my `Skip all breakpoints` option is DISABLED. It is just that the circular indications are missing.

Can anyone help?

**EDIT:**

I tried restarting Eclipse and cleaning build to no avail.

Comment: Have you check the **Annotation** preference page and made sure that *Breakpoints* are still set to be shown?

Comment: @nitind Would appreciate it if you could tell me where to find the Annotation preference page. I do not see it under `Window > Preferences`.

Comment: The Preferences dialog is searchable using the text field on the left.

Comment: @nitind Yes, my breakpoints are set to show in the vertical ruler. This is a good answer however. You should post it.

Comment: Doesn't solve your problem, though. The **Perspective** really shouldn't matter. Anything special about the files you're opening, or their location?

Comment: @nitind I am not sure if it would have solved my problem because the problem suddenly went away all on its own a little while ago. The breakpoints started appearing again, out of the blue. It was all very weird; I did not change anything but they went away and then, they came back on their own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **Annotation** preference page controls whether *Breakpoints* and other Markers/Annotations are shown in the **Vertical Ruler**, or using other means like underlining and background colors (which is why background coloring is usually not offered in the various **Syntax Coloring** preference pages). Like all of the preference pages, you can find it most easily by using the search text box in the left side of the **Preferences** Dialog, or through **Quick Access** (usually *Ctrl/Cmd*+3).

Apparently this was a temporary problem for @Tacocat, the reasons for which remain unknown.

Comment: To my observations a difference in the source to the binaries being debugged may also cause this (e.g. running version 1.2.3 while having 1.4.6 open).